# Android write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)

Tags: android, ioexception

I have a listview where after a click download a pdf file that show to the user.
But the app doesn't work well because in my logcat obtain error. I read forum, and other stackoverflow solutions but i doesn't resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance for the responses.

My logcat error:

```
    05-24 07:31:52.306: W/System.err(1003): java.io.IOException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
05-24 07:31:52.356: W/System.err(1003):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:462)
05-24 07:31:52.605: W/System.err(1003):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:187)
05-24 07:31:52.675: W/System.err(1003):     at com.example.impresainforma.GiornaliActivity.downloadURL(GiornaliActivity.java:108)
05-24 07:31:52.775: W/System.err(1003):     at com.example.impresainforma.GiornaliActivity$LoadGiornale.doInBackground(GiornaliActivity.java:74)
05-24 07:31:52.801: W/System.err(1003):     at com.example.impresainforma.GiornaliActivity$LoadGiornale.doInBackground(GiornaliActivity.java:1)
05-24 07:31:52.856: W/System.err(1003):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-24 07:31:52.906: W/System.err(1003):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-24 07:31:52.916: W/System.err(1003):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-24 07:31:52.996: W/System.err(1003):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-24 07:31:53.006: W/System.err(1003):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-24 07:31:53.006: W/System.err(1003):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-24 07:31:53.006: W/System.err(1003): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: write failed: ENOSPC (No space left on device)
05-24 07:31:53.016: W/System.err(1003):     at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
05-24 07:31:53.016: W/System.err(1003):     at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:187)
05-24 07:31:53.046: W/System.err(1003):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:197)
05-24 07:31:53.186: W/System.err(1003):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:457)
05-24 07:31:53.186: W/System.err(1003):     ... 10 more
05-24 07:31:53.376: A/libc(1003): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000005d0 (code=1), thread 1003 (.impresainforma)
```

I paste my class for more information

```
public class GiornaliActivity extends Activity {

    private Document m_doc = new Document();
    private PDFViewer m_vPDF = null;
    public static String dest = null;
    public static boolean pdf_downloadable = true;
    private Uri linkuri;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        linkuri = intent.getData();
        if (isOnline()) {
            Global.Init(this);
            Global.def_view=2;
            new LoadGiornale().execute();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Nessuna connessione di rete disponibile.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    private class LoadGiornale extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        Dialog progress;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(GiornaliActivity.this, "Caricamento giornale", "Attendere...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                if (pdf_downloadable) {
                    URL url = new URL(linkuri.toString());                  
                    dest = downloadURL(url, "mypdf.pdf");
                    pdf_downloadable = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dest;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progress.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    m_doc.Open(dest, null);
                    m_vPDF = new PDFViewer(GiornaliActivity.this);
                    m_vPDF.Open(0, m_doc);
                    setContentView(m_vPDF);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public String downloadURL(URL url, String fileName) throws IOException {
        String destination = null;
        try {
            destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + fileName;
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;

            while ((bytes = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return destination;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (GiornaliActivity.dest != null) {
            File delFile = new File(GiornaliActivity.dest);
            delFile.delete();
            pdf_downloadable = true;
            Global.RemoveTmp();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomizedListView.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would appear that you are out of disk space.

Comment: Ok! I run my app with the option -sdcard, but the size used was very small. I increased the size and now works very well. Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

mean that there is not enough memory left on the internal storage file system of the device.
i think this may help you

```
<manifest ..... android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```